# Is it possible to disable spellcheck in a textarea via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, spell-checking

Is it possible to disable spellcheck in a textarea via JavaScript?

I've been looking at the [HTML5 'spellcheck' attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking), and I can get it to work on its own. However, I'd like to be able to change this attribute via JavaScript.

After reading the documentation provided at the above link, I put together the following lines of code (snippets from a larger file; I know they won't work on their own):

```
document.querySelector("#editor").spellcheck = "false";
```

and

```
document.querySelector("#editor").spellcheck = "true";
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Have I made a mistake or misunderstood the documentation? (Unhelpfully, the JavaScript console in Google Chrome is not returning an error.) Or is there any other way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are setting it to the *String* `"true"` (which is a `true` value) and to the *String* `"false"` (which is also a `true` value).

Use *Booleans*, not *Strings*. Get rid of the quotes.

Comment: Also, use `document.getElementById("editor")` rather than `document.querySelector("#editor")`

Comment: From the HTML5 spec on spellcheck[1] it says the *string* false is parsed. Testing on an iPad on iOS5 shows that neither `element.spellcheck = false;` nor `element.setAttribute('spellcheck','false');` work.

[1] http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking

Comment: My comment above is wrong. However, testing on an iPad with iOS5 seems to show that neither `element.spellcheck = false;` nor `element.spellcheck = 'false';` nor `element.setAttribute('spellcheck','false');` work. Tried setting autocomplete, autocapitalize, autocorrect to off, and that doesn't seem to work either. Very frustrating!

Comment: Turns out that changing the attributes was ignored if the input *already* *has* *focus* (I was trying to set the attribute within the onfocus event). `element.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'OFF'); element.setAttribute('autocorrect', 'OFF');` worked for me if I did it when I created the input.

Comment: `el.autocorrect = el.autocomplete = el.autocapitalize = el.spellcheck = false;` works fine (unless input already has focus, in which case it doesn't work!).

Answer (score 2):

At least for me, the String/Boolean distinction doesn't affect HTML attributes in JavaScript—Javascript interprets `"false" == false`.

You may be running into issues with the spellcheck not being canceled because you're not forcing it to re-evaluate the textarea. To force this, try this code:

```
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
editor.spellcheck = false;
editor.focus();
editor.blur();
```

The focus forces the browser to re-evaluate the textarea, in this case with no spellcheck. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a basic attribute.

The following should work without library:

```
document.getElementById('editor').setAttribute('spellcheck', 'true'); // or false
```

and with jquery:

```
$('#editor').attr('spellcheck', 'true'); // or false
```

Comment: Using `setAttribute()` is usually a bad idea (it's broken in IE and doesn't do what a lot of people think). It's almost always better to use the corresponding property instead.